# How to Create a DLL of .csproj file

Tags: c#, csc

```
csc /target:library /out:MyMaths.dll ClassLibraryFunction.csproj
```

I am using this code to generate a DLL in VS.Cmd compiler for a whole solution. However, I am getting a compile error, and the DLL is not being generated.

Comment: That's nice.  Now was there a question?

Comment: Are you telling us or asking us? More info would be good

Comment: @skyfoot i am asking that how to Create dll for a hole application in c#

Comment: I feel this question is real, genuine and answerable. I'm reopening - I'll edit the question in a moment to improve it.

Comment: @MarcGravell thnks this is a real question notice that i am creating a DLL for hole project not .exe so how it will be possible .

Comment: @pratikgodha why can't you just change the csproj itself to be a library project?

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @HaemEternal at a guess: lots of syntax errors because xml (the csproj) is *not* C#, and `csc` is a C# compiler

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I figured that your answer below was correct; I was just hoping to get a little more info added into the question for the sake of people coming along later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csc` does not work with `.csproj` files. You have a few options:

1. use `msbuild`; for example

   ```
   msbuild ClassLibraryFunction.csproj
   ```

   noting that you may need to change the output-type of the project (in the IDE this is Project Properties, Application, Output type; in the csproj file this is `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`)
2. use `csc` with the `/recurse` switch; for example:

   ```
   csc /target:library /out:MyMaths.dll /recurse:*.cs
   ```

   (which will compile all the `.cs` files in the current folder or in sub-folders)
3. do nothing whatsoever, and just use the exe that you already have; a .NET exe can be referenced just like any other assembly, and any `public` types can be consumed

Comment: @pratikgodha a project **can be** a dll; you just set the project's output as library. The word is "whole", btw; not "hole" - that means something completely different.

Comment: yes i can add lib. to the new Application but on that time i am not able to access the classes. what i want when i will create a dll for a application1 which contains the classes and when i will create a new application2 and attach a lib. or dll into application2 i will be able to access all the classes .

Comment: @pratikgodha everything you have said is normal behaviour for a library. The only question I have is simply: are the types `public`? BTW: did you know you can also add a reference to an exe? So even if your application is currently an exe, you can **still** reference it from another project, and consume the types. As long as they are `public`.

Comment: yes i know that i can add reference .exe but when i am accessing that not able to call classes which it exe contains do you understand what i want and what i want to do ?

Comment: @pratikgodha allow me to say again: that should work fine. If you can't see the types, then you need to go and make them `public`.

Comment: you mean to say Class will be a **Public** then my all classes is publicly define but i am not able to call.

Comment: @pratik then my next guess would be: different namespaces (add a `using` directive). But it has nothing to do with whether it is built as an exe or a dll.

Comment: all the namespace and classes is ok when i will make a DLL for a single class and add it into reference this is then ok to call class but prob is to create a DLL for Whole Application.

Comment: @pratikgodha there is no fundamental difference between a dll for a single class and a dll/exe containing an entire application. Whatever you are doing wrong, it has nothing whatsoever to do with whether you build it as an exe or a dll

Comment: create application having a classes and create another application and add exe/dll of the first application then call classes if you will be able to access that class then please rep.

Comment: @pratikgodha yes, you can access the classes. If you can't, you've done something wrong, but I can't tell you what based on the very limited information available.

Comment: i told you that i am not able to access any class after attaching the dll/exe.

Comment: @pratikgodha then ... is there still a problem?

Comment: yes there is a prob i want to access classes in another application which is in first application dll/exe but still i am not able to call the classes

Comment: @pratikgodha I cannot answer that with the information you have presented, which has nothing whatsoever to do with the question you asked